# Integer variable getting set to 0 instead of null - Jsf 2.1, Weblogic

Tags: java, jsf-2, weblogic12c

I have a **JSF 2.0** application on **Weblogic 12c**. I have a variable of Integer type in an Entity accepting input type="text" on the JSF side.

The issue is, on save, the Integer variable is getting set to 0 if the user does not enter any value in the field. I need it to be **null**. I searched for previous questions but only found answers for Tomcat which didnt work for me. How do I fix this?

```
private Integer code;

public Integer getCode() {
    return this.code;
}

public void setCode(Integer code ) {
    this.code = code ;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116517/hinputtext-which-is-bound-to-integer-property-is-submitting-value-0-instead-of  By the way searching for "jsf integer null 0" was what I did.

Comment: @JoopEggen thats a solution for Tomcat :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282777/convert-empty-number-as-null - it seems the JSP Expression Language has an issue, and that could very well be that of apache.

Comment: @JoopEggen but I use weblogic and so I cant add that VM argument. Can I?

Comment: It would not hurt. Try it (in a local weblogic). I have forgotten how to do it with weblogic.

Comment: @JoopEggen didn't work ..

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer why it is happening, but to 'fix' the issue you might try something similar to this:

```
public void setCode(Integer code ) {
    if (code == null || code.intValue() == 0) {
        this.code = null;
    }
    this.code = code;
}
```

This would only 'work' as a fix if you know your code value should never actually be 0.

Comment: Thanks but this is an issue all over the code so this is not a viable solution for me :(

Comment: Ahh, too bad :(. Will let you know if I find an answer.