# Jboss + EL - interpret null Integer as null instead of 0

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss, el

I discovered that `EL` interpret `null Integer` object as `0`. How to achieve this problem? I found that I can use system property `org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO` but it didn't help (as far as I know it works for Tomcat but we use JBoss).

I use JBoss 6.0.1 GA, JSF 2.1.

Comment: Should work on Jboss just fine (your version uses tomcat under the covers). How do you pass it to the server? Does it show up in the startup process?

Comment: I've created `ServlerContextListener` and property is passed through `System.setProperty("org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO", "false")` as `@BalusC` wrote here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5225055/2069368.