# Migration from Glassfish 3.1 to Glassfish 4.0

Tags: spring-mvc, jsf-2, glassfish-4.1

There seems to be a problem with migrating from Glassfish 3.1 to Glassfish 4.x.

I am currently encountered with the following errors:

> StandardWrapperValve[DispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet DispatcherServlet threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getInt(TagAttributeImpl.java:175) at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachHandler.getEnd(ForEachHandler.java:266) at ......................

The code responsible for this works perfectly fine in Glassfish 3.1 but now fails in 4.x.

I've tried this answer out but no luck : [How to set -Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225013/coerce-to-zero-at-runtime)

Anyone who has encountered this issue?

Here is part of my applicationContext.xml stating the solution on the tutorial:

```
<bean id="trustStore" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetObject" value="#{@systemProperties}" />
            <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll" />
            <property name="arguments">
                <props>

                    <prop key="org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO">false</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Thank you.