# JSF can't get property of a value returned by a method with parameters

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I've been stuck on a problem which involves allowing an input field of type `Double` to be null or other values.

Since I'm working with automatically generated code, I can't touch the get / set methods for my object. Additionally, I am unable to modify server parameters, such as `-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO`.

My most recent solution was to make a wrapper object for the auto-generated object, which deals in `String` instead of `Double`. Here it is:

```
public class WrapperType {

    private AUTO_GENERATED_OBJECT autogen;

    public WrapperType(AUTO_GENERATED_OBJECT autogen) {
        this.autogen = autogen;
    }

    public String getOperation() {
        if (autogen.getOperation() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return autogen.getOperation() + "";
    }

    public void setOperation(String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            autogen.setOperation(null);
        } else {
            autogen.setOperation(Double.valueOf(value));
        }
    }
}
```

So all I have to do is, instead of calling the get/set on my autogenerated object, call the get/set on an equivilant wrapper, which can be obtained with something like:

```
public WrapperType convertVar(AUTO_GENERATED_OBJECT autogen) {
    return new WrapperType(autogen);
}
```

And then refer to it where needed:

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.convertVar(_var).operation}" />
```

Except that this doesn't work. I'm recieving an error that:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /operation/collections/tabs/page.xhtml  The class 'MyClass$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy' does not have the property 'convertVar'.
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this problem, or to overcome my requirement of both null and numeric values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this. Just use a @WebListener to modify the propery and get nulls intead of zeroes.

[coerce to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225013/coerce-to-zero-at-runtime/5225055#5225055)

Comment: Works like a charm. I shouldn't have given up so easily when I saw the COERCE_TO_ZERO solutions. Thanks, Julio.