# Make Size validator ignore null for optional fields in JSF JPA?

Tags: java, validation, jsf, wildfly, bean-validation

Lets say I have a Table with a text field called player that is null ok.
So nulls are allowed, but if not null (has a value) the size of the text/string must be between 10 and 100.
I have this to start:

```
@Column(name = "player", nullable = true)
@Size(min = 5, max = 100)
private String player;
```

But when Set the field to null the JSF page is throwing a validation error.

Is there a way to make the Size validator ignore nulls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `player` string is null then the `Size` constraint will not throw any exception. It's a best practice not to throw an error when the value is null (except for `NotNull` constraint or `NotEmpty` constraint). The fact is the player bean property value is probably an empty string and not a null value, so the constraint throw an exception, because JSF sends an empty string when nothing is typed in the component. In order to JSF sending a null value you have to add some content in `web.xml` file as said in the Java EE Tutorial:

> In order for the Bean Validation model to work as intended, you must set the context parameter javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL to true in the web deployment descriptor file, web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>
        javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL
    </param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If eventually (depending on versions) the parameter doesn't work as expected see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880017/javax-faces-interpret-empty-string-submitted-values-as-null-does-not-work-anymor) for troubleshooting.

**EDIT:**

You could also try not applying the previous parameter and instead using the `Pattern` constraint with a Regex pattern similar to `(^$|^[a-zA-Z]{3,7}$)`.

Comment: Kudos to you, you nailed it @lametaweb (muchas gracias). The string was not filled and my app was sending an empty string which of course fails the validation. After adding the context-param `javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` as suggested - it works flawlessly. Cheers.

Comment: @Mario Peck, please Mark the answer as correct,if it helped you :)

Comment: Hi @Mario Peck if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: Hi @Mario Peck you should see a green tick beside my answer, please revise it. Thanks!