# Tomcat 8 (and 9) coerce behaviour, null strings are incorrectly set as empty strings

Tags: jsf, el, jsf-2.2, tomcat8, apache-tomee

I have just migrated to Tomcat 8. I used to work with system property `org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false` so empty strings, numbers, booleans etc. are treated as `null`.

In Tomcat 8, EL 3.0, it is supposed to be the default but it is in fact converting `null` string to empty string `""` on JSF side.

It is supposed to be a [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57309) and it is supposed to be corrected but I'm not able to get it working in TomEE snapshot (Tomcat 8.0.27.0, MyFaces 2.2.8).

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31020728

Comment: Yes, indeed, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in the EL 3.0 specification. Since EL 3.0, as consequence of overzealous fix of [JSP spec issue 184](http://web.archive.org/web/20150513195447/https://java.net/jira/browse/JSP_SPEC_PUBLIC-184), `null` will be coerced back to empty string before the model value setter is invoked. Basically, the `javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` doesn't have any affect anymore. See also [JSF issue 3071](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/3075) and [EL spec issue 18](https://github.com/javaee/el-spec/issues/18).

Basically, to solve this problem you need to provide either a custom EL resolver, or to replace/upgrade the EL implementation (or simply the whole server as it's the one actually providing EL out the box) to a version with the bugfix. The [Tomcat issue 57309](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57309) which you linked is not related to this particular EL 3.0 issue of unnecessary coercion from null to empty string, it's only related to Tomcat's ignorance of the custom EL resolver.

You can solve this problem in two ways:

1. Provide a custom EL resolver like below. Make sure that you use Tomcat 8.0.16 or newer, as specified in the Tomcat issue report you found.

   ```
    public class EmptyToNullStringELResolver extends ELResolver {

        @Override
        public Class<?> getCommonPropertyType(ELContext context, Object base) {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Object convertToType(ELContext context, Object value, Class<?> targetType) {
            if (value == null && targetType == String.class) {
                context.setPropertyResolved(true);
            }

            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<FeatureDescriptor> getFeatureDescriptors(ELContext context, Object base) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getType(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReadOnly(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property, Object value) {
            // NOOP.
        }

    }
   ```

   In order to get it to run, register as below in `faces-config.xml`:

   ```xml
    <application>
        <el-resolver>com.example.EmptyToNullStringELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
   ```

   ---
2. Or, switch to Oracle EL. They already fixed it in [version 3.0.1 b05](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.el/3.0.1-b05/) which has been available since 7 July 2014 (just pick the [newest](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.el/) one which is 3.0.1-b10 as of today).

   Just drop `javax.el.jar` file in `/WEB-INF/lib` and add the below context param to `web.xml` in order to instruct MyFaces to use the Oracle EL implementation instead:

   ```xml
    <context-param>     
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
    </context-param>
   ```

   In case you're using Mojarra, use param name `com.sun.faces.expressionFactory`.

As I got momentarily confused myself too, I blogged to get it all right: [The empty String madness](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/10/the-empty-string-madness.html).

###See also:

- [javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL does not work anymore since Java EE 7 / EL 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880017/javax-faces-interpret-empty-string-submitted-values-as-null-does-not-work-anymor/31020728#31020728)

Comment: Only the first solution works for me. I'm using joinfaces: https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces

Comment: I recently tried to upgrade from EE7 to EE8 by moving fra Tomcat 8.5 to 9.0.7 (Weld 3, Mojarra 2.3 and Jersey 2.26). Suddenly, this null/empty string started playing mayhem with my view parameters.

I tried to make sense of the recommendations in this post but failed. I'm hoping BalusC will shed light on what I may be experiencing siden I was expecting all this to have blown over by now.

Comment: Upgrading from Tomcat 8.5 to 9.0.12, solution #2 above using the sun jar no longer works for me. However, returning to https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc EmptyToNullStringConverter published here http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/10/the-empty-string-madness.html results in empty strings being set as null on form submit.

Comment: I'm unable to simply add the custom EL resolver due to my dependence on PrimeFaces: org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver