# Why can't I access getter in bidirectional value binding's write-back phase?

Tags: jsf, el, propertynotfoundexception

I'm trying to establish a bidirectional data binding as follows:

```
<h:outputText value="#{cc.getAspect('meta').metaInfo.previousValue}" />
```

But I'm getting the following Exception, *only* when writing back though (the value is initially displayed just fine upon loading the page):

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /resources/meta.xhtml @23,124 
value="#{cc.getAspect('meta').metaInfo.previousValue}":
The class 'org.foo.client.jsf.UIComponent' does not have the property 'getAspect'.
```

Now I'm wondering:

1) The `getAspect` method is definitely there (double checked, also it works upon read after all). By "property" does JSF denote a "field" and is actually implicitly trying to access `setgetAspect` or somthing? If so, why?

2) Why would it even try to **write**, that is to access a setter, on the `getAspect` in the first place?? The only value that is or should be written is `previousValue`, just located down the object path `cc.getAspect('meta').metaInfo.previousValue` which only **reads** the meta aspect via getAspect.

Any ideas greatly appreciated, thanks

**EDIT:** Environment: JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA, JSF Implementation: Mojarra 2.1.19

Comment: Which EL impl/version? Tried latest or alternate?

Comment: @BalusC Sorry, updated the question, in the meantime I'm searching wich EL Version that actually is. Can't try different, constrained to this environment

Comment: If it's server-provided (and you didn't customize server) just telling server impl/version is also sufficient. Given that Mojarra 2.1.19 is ancient I wouldn't wonder if your server/EL is also ancient. Problem could possibly be solved by just upgrading server/EL. Try an isolated test if necessary.

Comment: @BalusC Updated the question. Alas, updating is not an option :( So are you saying this *should* work theoretically or according to the spec and sounds like a bug in older versions?

Comment: It simply must work theoretically/technically/specified/intuitively. Just did a quick test, works just fine for me on both Tomcat 8.0.30 (latest Apache EL) and WildFly 9.0.2 (latest Oracle EL). It's by the way possible to switch EL impl from WAR on. Give it a try, see option 2 of http://stackoverflow.com/a/33420995