# RELATED: Problem with null versus empty String when updating to JSF 2.3 (Mojarra) on Tomcat 9

Tags: jsf, el, tomcat9

The application seemed to start fine but I am now plagued by empty strings being applied to view parameters. `javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` parameter was already set to true in my web.xml.

Here's what I did to upgrade:

1. Updated JSF artifacts: from **javax.faces:javax.faces-api:2.2 and org.glassfish:javax.faces:2.2.15** to **javax.faces:javax.faces-api:2.3 and org.glassfish:javax.faces:2.3.8**.
2. Updated namespace in **faces-config.xml**.
3. Updated namespace in **beans.xml** to enable 2.0.
4. Updated **web.xml** to servlet 4.0.
5. Added **javax.faces.ENABLE_CDI_RESOLVER_CHAIN** and **javax.faces.ENABLE_WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT** in **web.xml**.
6. I even added a JSF 2.3 activator class even though it seemed as if it was redundant.
7. **OmniFaces** updated from 2.6.9 to 3.2.

EDIT: Turns out this is related to [Tomcat 8 (and 9) coerce behaviour, null strings are incorrectly set as empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334192/tomcat-8-coerce-behaviour-null-strings-are-incorrectly-set-as-empty-strings)

But as stated in the title I'm trying to migrate to **JSF 2.3 on Tomcat 9** (9.0.12). The previous question and BalusC blog does not directly address this case. I should also state that the application was running on JDK11 without problems before this.

From the previous question I learned the using Oracles EL implementation could work but I'm getting:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: arraycopy: last source index 16 out of bounds for byte[9]
at java.base/java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at com.sun.faces.util.ByteArrayGuardAESCTR.decrypt(ByteArrayGuardAESCTR.java:157)
at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash$PreviousNextFlashInfoManager.decode(ELFlash.java:1414)
at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.getCurrentFlashManager(ELFlash.java:1237)
at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.doPrePhaseActions(ELFlash.java:641)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:214)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:133)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
```

Comment: What about your EL versions?

Comment: I've not touched that as it was not part of my Gradle build files. Isn't EL bundled by Tomcat?

Comment: it is, but if you included something in your own project it might have played a role.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334192/tomcat-8-coerce-behaviour-null-strings-are-incorrectly-set-as-empty-strings ??? I found this by posting "tomcat 9 javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL site:stackoverflow.com" in a searchengine https://www.google.com/search?q=tomcat+9+javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL

Comment: That seems REALLY relevant. My first reaction is that I was already on Tomcat 8.5 without this being a problem, but I'll check this out right away.

Comment: BalusC tries to summarize his findings in http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/10/the-empty-string-madness.html but there's no specific mention of JSF 2.3. I did not have this problem with JSF 2.2.

Comment: Yes I know... Still, did it fix it for you? Then maybe we can 'ping' @BalusC to update his blog

Comment: Maybe you should create a 'new' question. about the 'upgrade or usage' of the Oracle EL (which version btw???)

Comment: I'm also facing this problem now. Wildfly 16 bundled with Mojarra 2.3.9. + JDK 11

Answer (score -1):

In your **web.xml**, include:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>
        javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL
    </param-name>
    <param-value>
        **false**
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```