# Custom ELResolver workaround for INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL

Tags: jsf-2, el

I'm using JSF 2.2 with the Mojarra 2.2.10 release along with Glassfish 4.0.

I would like to convert empty submitted string as null so I tried to use:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But it doesn't work as reported by other users [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880017/interpret-empty-string-submitted-values-as-null-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575283/jsf-2-2-interpret-empty-string-submitted-values-as-null-not-working?rq=1)

So the workaround is to define a custom EL resolver ([top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21902404/2118909) from the first link) which is declared in faces-config.xml.

However, the creates another major issue to me: in my .xhtml pages, a call to `#{request.contextPath}` is now converted to **null** when `#{request.contextPath}` returns an **empty string**

example.xhtml:

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/book/1">My link</a>
```

becomes

```
 <a href="null/book/1">My link</a>
```