# How to make number input area initially empty instead of 0 or 0.00?

Tags: jsf, input, numbers, zero

I have an input place that should get a number. I want it to be displayed as empty. However when I run my program, I get 0 or 0.00 as default. How can I make it empty?

Comment: Should work if you map to an object type (Integer, Long, Double) and make it null by default.

Comment: They are mapped and null but still continues.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This will happen if you bound the value to a primitive instead of its wrapper representation. The primitive `int` always defaults to `0` and the primitive `double` always defaults to `0.0`. You want to use `Integer` or `Double` (or `BigDecimal`) instead.

E.g.:

```java
public class Bean {

    private Integer number;

    // ...
}
```

Then there are two more things to take into account when processing the form submit. First, you need to instruct JSF to interpret empty string submitted values as `null`, otherwise EL will still coerce the empty string to `0` or `0.0`. This can be done via the following context parameter in `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Second, if you're using Tomcat/JBoss or any server which uses Apache EL parser under the covers, then you need to instruct it to not coerce `null` to `0` or `0.0` in case of `Number` types by the following VM argument (it's unintuitively dealing with `Number` types as if they are primitives):

```
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false
```

#### See also:

- [The empty string madness](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/10/the-empty-string-madness.html)
- [h:inputText which is bound to Integer property is submitting value 0 instead of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116517/hinputtext-which-is-bound-to-integer-property-is-submitting-value-0-instead-of)
- [h:inputText which is bound to String property is submitting empty string instead of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203322/hinputtext-which-is-bound-to-string-property-is-submitting-empty-string-instead)
- [javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL does not work anymore since Java EE 7 / EL 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880017/javax-faces-interpret-empty-string-submitted-values-as-null-does-not-work-anymor)

Comment: Hi @BalusC, what file do I need to add the VM argument to and where is it located?

Comment: @Erick: It needs to go in the `java` launch command of the server. It's not necessarily in a file and depends on how you're launching the server.

Answer (score 2):

I don't disagree with previous answers given, but I think you might be looking for

```
<h:inputText id="number" binding="#{controller.inputBox}" value="#{controller.number}" >
     <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{controller.preRenderInput}" />
</h:inputText>
```

and inside the controller

```
private double number; // getters and setters
private UIInput inputBox; // getters and setters
public void preRenderInput() {
        // if it is the first request
        if(!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
            inputBox.setValue("");
        }
}
```

JSF 2.0+

Answer (score 0):

You can use inputNumber in primefaces-extension instead of inputText.
Like this

```
<pe:inputNumber  />
```

Answer (score -5):

In your XHTML code, assume you have your input field as :

```
<h:inputText id="newname" value="#{youAction.newName}"
        style="width:130px" styleClass="form">
</h:inputText>
```

In your Managed Bean Action Class, map this field as :

```
@ManagedBean(name="yourAction")
public class YourAction {

   private String newName;
   ...

   // Add Getter & Setter Methods
   ... 
}
```

By doing in this way, you won't get 0 or 0.00 as default value in your input fields.

Comment: my question is about numeric values, I do not have any problem with strings. But I still have the problem for integers and doubles.

Comment: @GaryLeather - When you want to make use of the value, why don't you convert the value to the type you want.