# Updating BigDecimal based inputText is setting its value to zero

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, bigdecimal

I am updating a `p:inputText` from a `p:commandButton`.

*View component:*

```
<p:commandButton value="Search" action="#{bean.retrieveInfo}" update="amount"/>
<p:inputText id="amount" value="#{bean.amount}"/>
```

*Bean Field:*

```
private BigDecimal amount;
public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

When the page is loaded, as inspected, *`amount`* is null in the setter but when click on command button updated `p:inputText`, the backing bean field *`amount`* gets initialized and takes up a zero intValue as shown below:

[image]

`BigDecimal` being a wrapper, I wanted to keep it uninitialized (`null`), as it is, until I initialize the same. Until the end of the command button listener code, *`amount`* was null. And then `update="amount"` invoked the setter with an initialized (non null) zero value. Don't know why and where it is getting initialized. Please have a look into it.

Comment: You didn't tell much about your environment and configuration, but is this acceptable as dupe?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334188/how-to-make-number-input-area-initially-empty-instead-of-0-or-0-00/