# Primefaces inputNumber emptyValue="empty" is not empty

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

JSF 2.2
Primefaces 6.0

The "emptyValue" attribute of p:inputNumber seems straightforward, and yet it is not working

```
   <p:inputNumber id="wsMaxInput" emptyValue="empty"
      value="#{officeResults.wsCountMax}" maxValue="3000"
      minValue="0" styleClass="ondInput" />
```

Not only does it not look empty (I'm not sure if picture attaching will work from here), but when I hit "submit" the value is set to zero when it should be null.

[image]

What am I missing about this component?

Comment: The problem might be with `minValue="0"` because it will be resetting value to `0`!

Comment: Check your backingbean... is the `#{officeResults.wsCountMax}`  an int? I am 99.9% sure it is: https://www.google.nl/search?q=jsf+default+value+int+stackoverflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make number input area initially empty instead of 0 or 0.00?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334188/how-to-make-number-input-area-initially-empty-instead-of-0-or-0-00)

Comment: OfficeResults.java: "private Integer wsCountMax".  When I remove minValue="0" it populates with "0.00" . So neither of these comments apply.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: In fact, when I have 2 components side-by-side wsCountMin and wsCountMax and I have one emptyValue="zero" and one emptyValue="empty" they are both populated identically with "0.00"

Comment: I just found the bug - my bug.  I had registered a converter when I declared wscountmin as a viewParam at the top of the page.  The converter was causing this.  I forgot all about it and just saw it.  I removed the converter and got the desired result.