# Java EE 7, EL 3.0 spec. changes with respect to type coercion

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, el, coercion, wildfly-8

So I've been away from Java EE for six months and I'm now back and migrating an application to [Java EE 7](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr342/) and I am noticing that [JSR-341/ the EL 3.0 spec.](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=341) contains changes in the section *Type Conversion* (now, section 1.23; formerly, section 1.18).

In section 1.23, the very first rule in all of the various types *except String* is that if X is null and Y is not a primitive return null.  This is a much welcome change.

So my first question is: with regard to section 1.23.3 *Coerce A to Number type N*,

In EL 2.1:

> If A is null or "", return 0.

In EL 3.0:

> If A is null and N is not a primitive type, return null.
>   Else if A is null or "", return 0.

Is it now no longer necessary to set the system property `org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false`?

---

Next, there are a couple of other changes that beg questions:

In the very first subsection, section 1.23.1 (formerly 1.18.1) *To Coerce a Value X to Type Y*, the rule for the general case is given.  Now, a new bullet has been added (emphasis mine):

> If X is null and Y is not a primitive type and *also not a String*, return null.

In section 1.23.2 *Coerce A to String* the first two bullets have been flipped around.  They are now in the following order:

> If A is null: return “”
>   Otherwise, if A is String: return A

It appears that whereas before a null String remained a null String after coercion, now a null String is coerced to an empty String.  So my second question is: am I reading this correctly, that the String is now treated differently than the other kinds of objects with respect to coercion?  If so, why?

Such a change seems counterintuitive because as we all know null has special meaning. Moreover, such a change is alarming because it can adversely affect the code that I'm migrating, which was was originally written against an older spec.

And, finally, my third question is: what about bean validation?  Does this mean that now `@NotNull` annotations on Strings in backing beans are useless because coerced String values can never be null?  I doubt it, but I'd like to know how the new changes all work together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is it now no longer necessary to set the system property `org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false`?*

When you're using [Apache EL parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116517/hinputtext-which-is-bound-to-integer-property-is-submitting-value-0-instead-of) (as used in among others Tomcat), that's correct. In other words, they have indeed *finally* implemented [my own request](http://web.archive.org/web/20150513195447/https://java.net/jira/browse/JSP_SPEC_PUBLIC-184) on that.

Given that you're using Wildfly, that should however not really be applicable in your particular case, as it doesn't use Apache EL, but just [EL RI](http://arjan-tijms.blogspot.nl/2014/05/implementation-components-used-by.html) (like as in GlassFish) which had this part already right from the beginning on. This was just a minor oversight in the EL spec and Tomcat guys were just very picky on this (they had this part right too until Tomcat 6.0.16 and then mangled it in order to "comply" the oversight in the spec and after a lot of complaints they added this system property in 6.0.17 in order to be able to turn it off).

---

> *am I reading this correctly, that the String is now treated differently than the other kinds of objects with respect to coercion?*

Nope. The ordering shouldn't matter, result would be the same all time. `null` is not a `String` anyway. The ordering has likely been changed for clarity and simplification of the implementation.

In JSF perspective, this EL spec section only concerns writing results of EL expressions to HTML output (which is of `String` type), not updating model values with submitted/coerced/converted/validated values, as you seemed to expect. For that, you still need the following `web.xml` context parameter to let JSF interpret empty string submitted values as `null`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This part has not changed as compared to JSF 2.0/2.1.

Comment: I've been looking for a resource such as Ajan Tijms' blog post [Implementation components used by various Java EE servers](http://arjan-tijms.blogspot.nl/2014/05/implementation-components-used-by.html) for a week now.  So glad that you referenced it.

Comment: I disagree about your last paragraph: EL is used both to read and write backing bean properties, and `INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` does not change that. That is, even if the UIInput passes null to the EL 3.0 implementation, the EL implementation helpfully converts it to "" prior to invoking the setter. This issue has been filed at [JAVASERVERFACES-3071](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3071).

Comment: @meriton: indeed, the behavior has unexpectedly changed since EL 3.0. We've discussed this internally in JSF expert group, see a.o. https://java.net/projects/javaserverfaces-spec-public/lists/jsr372-experts/archive/2014-10/message/69 I will blog later about it. This all is really awkward.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I also found [EL_SPEC-18](https://java.net/jira/browse/EL_SPEC-18). And yes, it *is* awkward.