# There's some way to get value through specific getter in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

i've a POJO class with primitive types, but when the values are show in the JSF page, they appears to be filled by ZERO.

i think about construct an alternative GETTER method, returning String type with empty value.

But, i can associate an alternative getter in JSF page? because we have 2 versions of same get and set method.

Comment: Why don't you change your primitive to it's respective object wrapper?

Comment: i didn't understand your suggestion :/

Comment: Refer this (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: i'm confused yet... because, all my form inputs are associated with some bean property. Like <input value="#{bean.beanProperty}"/> where the framework can understand that he needs to acess through default getter. But i can't use some String.valueOf('') inside my input value... right?

Comment: If  your beanProperty is 'int' then its default value is zero (default value of int is 0). If it is wrapper class Integer as then it's default value is null;

Comment: i can understand... but, i can't imagine how can i put this solution in the code. The POJO are used by many other functionalities, i'm trying to not prejudice the rest of the team. I imagine, this solution is located inside my getter, right?

Comment: For now you try this <h:outputText value="#{bean.beanProperty == '0' ? '' : bean.beanProperty}" />. But I suggest you to modify int to its wrapper class. It would be nice if you provide little code.

Comment: Also have a look int this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116517/hinputtext-which-is-bound-to-integer-property-is-submitting-value-0-instead-of