# Multiple validators on one field with JSF bean validation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

i am trying to make multiple validation one one field

```
    @NotBlank(message = "{name.required}")
    @Max(value = 25, message = "{long.value}")
    public String name;
```

JSF:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{person.name}" size="20">
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="name" style="color:red" />
```

but when i leave the field empty, it shows both error messages.

any ideas how to handle both cases, validate the empty, and maximum length independently.

Comment: it's wierd, i don't know why, but when i used @Size and give it max,everything works as expected, any ideas ?

Comment: `@Size` and `@Max` are not the same. The `@Size` validates the length of the string input value. `@Max` validates the numerical value of any number input value. E.g. 26 would not pass on `@Max(25)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your JSF 2 configuration interpret empty submitted values as `""` and not `null` then :

The `@NotBlank` validator returns `false` because your annotated
   string is empty.

The `@Max` validator returns `false` because according to hibernate implementation (I guess you are using hibernate implementation base on your previous posts).

```
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        //null values are valid
        if ( value == null ) {
            return true;
        }
        try {
            return new BigDecimal( value ).compareTo( BigDecimal.valueOf( maxValue ) ) != 1;
        }
        catch ( NumberFormatException nfe ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In your case the `value` String parameter contains an empty value ("") and the  BigDecimal(String) constructor throws an exception and then the validator returns `false`.

You have two possible solutions:

- Configure JSF to [`interpret empty submitted values as null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203322/hinputtext-return-a-empty-string-instead-of-null) (or)
- Change your field `name` type to numerical instead of String.

Comment: Nice catch! In that case the OP can also just use `@NotNull` instead of the hibernate-impl-specific `@NotBlank`.