# How to express 'null' value from web service as real null or empty string instead of 'null' string

Tags: java, string, web-services, jsf-2, null

In my application, I am using JSF and Java Web Services. When any of my web-service functions return a `null` value, it is always expressed as a "null" string. As a consequence, I cannot use EL expressions like `#{empty object}` to test for `null` values or empty strings.

I'd like to ask if there's a way to configure such that Java Web Services will return `null` value as an empty string OR JSF/EL can understand "null" string as `null` value.

Comment: Can you share web service code?

Comment: `#{empty object.stringProperty}` will return `true` when `stringProperty is either `null` or `empty`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203322/hinputtext-return-a-empty-string-instead-of-null

Comment: @rdcrng: not if `stringProperty` is `"null"` as in OP's case.

Comment: @Shamim: you clearly misunderstood the problem.

Comment: I clearly misunderstood it as well. :/

Comment: This is strange. If the webservice call is truly return "null" as in nothing, JAX-B (you *are* using a JAX-B based ws?) will simply omit the tag/member on the response object. Do you have `required="false", nillable="true"` on the field that's supposed to be null?

Answer (score 0):

if you,

- using SOAP, you must remember that the SOAP message is an XML, so you can return an empty String as `null` or `empty object`
- using HTTP or REST, you must remember that the HTTP using type of `String` to serialize the object and informations

So you have choose:

- right serialization of return objects. If you using SOAP, remember Base64 encoding.
- right output value for errors. You can serialize directly the exceptions or your custom message codes.

I hope to help you.