# Using RestEasy, optionally pass a parameter as JSON in the POST

Tags: json, ajax, rest, resteasy, endpoint

I have the following REST endpoint:

```
@POST
@Path("/id/{id}/doSomething")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response doSomething(@PathParam("id") final String id, MyObject foo) {
    // does some stuff; checks for a null foo and handles it
}
```

The MyObject class has a single String field called `justification`.

I'd like to be able to hit this endpoint with no content at all, or with JSON that maps to the `MyObject` class. I'd like either way to work. In other words, `foo` can be instantiated, or `foo` can be null; I have code to handle both cases.

The problem is that the JSON content appears to be *required* to this endpoint, not *optional*. So during testing, I'm *having* to send JSON to the endpoint, or I receive a 500 error. Even if that JSON is just `{}` (I can also send `{ justification: "blah blah" }` and that works as well). But sending no content at all results in a failed call; never even hits the endpoint.

So, my question is, how can I set this endpoint up so that I can POST to it with no content at all, or with JSON in the body that maps to `foo`, and have either way work?

Ultimately, I just need a way for the user to be able to send a justification to this endpoint, but not have to. And because justifications can be long, I can't have it as a query param or a path param.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to be able to hit the `endpoint` with no content at all because your `endpoint` says `@Consumes({MediaType.APPLCIATION_JSON})`. Besides there has to be some content while you're trying to `POST` to a class while using a web service.
Like you said, even if it is a `NULL` or a `{}`, it doesn't matter as long as it has some content coming in. 
Passing no content to the service works only when you're making a `GET` request. 
For all other `HTTP methods` such as `POST`,`PUT` and `DELETE`, you will mandatorily **HAVE** to send some data. 
As a solution to your problem, what you possibly could do is that - check if the content you have received is a `NULL` or a `{}` and do no processing at all for them.

If you still have a confusion in the answer, depending upon whether you're using `SOAP` or `REST`, this thread should help you. 
[How to express 'null' value from web service as real null or empty string instead of 'null' string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254184/how-to-express-null-value-from-web-service-as-real-null-or-empty-string-instea)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't be satisfactory for me because that means having the UI pass in at lease `{}` every time. Fundamentally, that seems hacky to me. I found a solution that sort of disproves what you suggested, but I may be misunderstanding your response. I'm about to post it, so, respectfully, you're welcome to provide comments.

Comment: Sure! Since you say you have found a post, maybe my solution is wrong too. Do post it, will take a look :)

Comment: Posted. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted by writing a second method annotated with the same REST path. This second method does not have an `@Consumes` statement, and does not have the second parameter in its method declaration. Looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("id/{id}/doSomething")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response doSomethingWithoutJustification(@PathParam("id") final String id) {
    doSomething(id, null);
}
```

This new method maps to the same path, but does not expect JSON and doesn't expose a second parameter. So when I POST with nothing in the request body at all, it hits `doSomethingWithoutJustification`, and when I *do* provide JSON in the request body, it hits `doSomething`. Of course, if I provide anything other than valid JSON in the request body, I receive a 500 response from the service, as I'd expect.

I'd hoped to specify an optional parameter with a single method, but this solution works perfectly.