# How to Use @NotNull Annotation Correctly?

Tags: jsf, bean-validation

I have used @NotNull annotation on Java bean class for JSF in register page. But it is not working as expceted.

Here is my xhtml page part :

```
User Name : <h:inputText value="#{user.userName}" />
```

And here is my Java bean part :

```
@NotNull(message = "User name cannot be null")
private String userName;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
```

But it still save userName to database(PostgreSQL) as ''. So technically it is not null. 
I know may be I must also make not null that column on database. But what for we use @NotNull annotation then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [h:inputText which is bound to String property is submitting empty string instead of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203322/hinputtext-which-is-bound-to-string-property-is-submitting-empty-string-instead)

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want to use is `@NotBlank`. Here is some [reference](https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-not-null-empty-blank) between `@NotNull`,`@NotEmpty`, and `@NotBlank`.

```
public class UserNotBlank {

    @NotBlank(message = "Name may not be blank")
    private String name;

    // standard constructors / getters / toString

}
```

> @NotNull: a constrained CharSequence, Collection, Map, or Array is valid as long as it’s not null, but it can be empty
>
> @NotEmpty: a constrained CharSequence, Collection, Map, or Array is valid as long as it’s not null and its size/length is greater than zero
>
> @NotBlank: a constrained String is valid as long as it’s not null and the trimmed length is greater than zero

Comment: `@NotNull` still can be used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203322/hinputtext-which-is-bound-to-string-property-is-submitting-empty-string-instead